# Add a static list to a new Pandas Dataframe column via apply

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a complex function that generates a `list` for each row in a `Pandas` `dataframe`. I'd like to make that `list` the value for each row in a new column called `mylist`.

The ability of Pandas to do this seems dependent on the number of columns in the starting dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'D'],
                        ['B', 'E'],
                        ['C', 'F']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'D', 'G'],
                        ['B', 'E', 'H'],
                        ['C', 'F', 'I']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

def add_list(row):
    return [1,3, 3]

df['mylist'] = df.apply(add_list, axis=1)
print df
```

yields:

```
  col1 col2       list
0    A    D  [1, 3, 3]
1    B    E  [1, 3, 3]
2    C    F  [1, 3, 3]
```

This additional code yields `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1`. Why should the number of columns in the starting `dataframe` have an impact?

```
df1['mylist'] = df1.apply(add_list, axis=1)
print df1
```

If I change the function to the below (adding one element), then there is no error:

```
def add_list(row):
    return [1,3, 3, 4]
```

expected output:

```
  col1 col2  col3      list
0    A    D    G   [1, 3, 3]
1    B    E    H   [1, 3, 3]
2    C    F    I   [1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: What is the actual output you're looking for?

Comment: @JoeR added expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bizarre behaviour. A solution seems to be to return a tuple instead of a list.

```
def add_list(row):
    return (1, 3, 3)

df1['mylist'] = df1.apply(add_list, axis=1).apply(list)
```

In the last line you'll notice the tuples are converted to lists once they are in the dataframe.

Comment: huh that is really strange...Is this a bug in the code?

Comment: Looks buggy to me! But with this solution it seems like not such a big deal

Comment: yeah, it works. I can then convert the items back to a list with with a `lambda` function if needed.